# Clarification about Infinite Sums in Jech's Set Theory 3rd Edition

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

On page 57 in the 3rd Edition of Jech's Set Theory, he begins with the elaboration on cardinal exponentiation. To that end the Hausdorff formula is introduced by noticing that for a regular cardinal $\kappa$,

\begin{equation}
  \kappa^\lambda = \cup_{\alpha < \kappa} \alpha^\lambda,
\end{equation}

with $\lambda$ denoting an infinite cardinal. From this Jech-apparently obviously-concludes that

\begin{equation}
  \kappa^\lambda = \sum_{\alpha < \kappa} |\alpha|^\lambda.
\end{equation}

My question is about the above conclusion.

On page 52 infinite sums are defined for *disjoint families*. This prerequisite appears not to be met by $\{\alpha^\lambda\}_{\alpha < \kappa}$, since $\beta < \gamma \implies \beta^\lambda \subseteq \gamma^\lambda$. My question is therefore why Jech applies the definition of inifinite sums, despite $\{\alpha^\lambda\}_{\alpha < \kappa}$ not being a disjoint family.

Appendix: Unless I have completely misunderstood something, I would guess that the answer to my question lies in the axiom of choice, i.e., we could replace $\{\alpha^\lambda\}_{\alpha < \kappa}$ with a disjoint family $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha < \kappa}$, $|X_\alpha| = |\alpha|$. Is this the right line of thinking?

Comment: Just as equality of sets is two containments, many equalities in cardinal arithmetic are really two inequalities. In the case at hand, it should be obvious the right-hand side is no larger than the other. For the other, find an injection from the set of functions on the left to a disjoint union of sets coding the right hand side. You are right that one cannot directly apply the definition in p. 52. On the other hand, once one is aware of the strategy I outlined, the equality should follow obviously, as Jech suggests.

Comment: Without the Axiom of Choice we cannot define the  ordinal $\kappa^{\lambda}$ when $\kappa$  is an ordinal greater than $2$ and $\lambda$ is an infinite ordinal.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: That is absolute nonsense.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Without AC how would you define the ordinal $2^{\omega}$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: That's a loaded question. "Without a knife, how did you murder your mother?", well, I didn't murder anyone. And $2^\omega$ is a set which may or may not have a well-ordering to it. But since you brought this up, how do you define *the ordinal* $2^\omega$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Without AC, I don't.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: So... $\omega$ has no power set without choice?

Comment: Dear @AndrésE.Caicedo,
Thank you very much for your comment. I am rather preoccupied at the moment, but I will give thought to your reply as soon as possible and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll turn the comment into an answer to expand it a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the regularity of $\kappa$ and the fact that the infinite cardinal $\lambda$ is less than $\kappa$, Jech notes that 
 $$ \kappa^\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}\alpha^\lambda, $$
where both sides are understood as sets of functions. From this, he claims that, as cardinals, 
 $$ \kappa^\lambda=\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}|\alpha|^\lambda. $$
This would be obvious if the sets $\alpha^\lambda$ were disjoint as $\alpha$ varies but, as you point out, this is clearly not the case.

You suggest instead to replace these sets by disjoint copies, say replacing $\alpha$ by $\hat\alpha=\{\alpha\}\times\alpha$ for each $\alpha<\kappa$. This changes the union $\bigcup_\alpha\alpha^\lambda$ into the disjoint union $\bigcup_\alpha\hat\alpha^\lambda$. Note that there is an obvious injection from the former into the latter: Given any function $f\in\bigcup_\alpha\alpha^\lambda$, find the least $\alpha$ such that $f\!:\lambda\to\alpha$, and map $f$ to its copy in $\hat\alpha^\lambda$.

This means that 
 $$ \kappa^\lambda\le\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}|\alpha|^\lambda. $$
However, Jech is claiming more, namely, equality rather than the inequality we just showed. 
Luckily for us, the inequality 
 $$ \sum_{\alpha<\kappa}|\alpha|^\lambda\le\kappa^\lambda $$
is quite easy to establish: First, for each $\alpha<\kappa$, $|\alpha|^\lambda\le\kappa^\lambda$, so $\sum_{\alpha<\kappa}|\alpha|^\lambda \le \sum_{\alpha<\kappa}\kappa^\lambda=\kappa\cdot\kappa^\lambda=\kappa^\lambda$. Note that this is the only place where we used that $\lambda$ is infinite (in fact, it suffices that $\lambda>0$).

From the two inequalities, the claimed equality now follows. Let me close by pointing out that this is a really useful heuristic: just as equality of sets is two containments, many equalities in cardinal arithmetic are really two inequalities.

In the case at hand, one of the inequalities turned out to be obvious upon inspection. This is actually not so uncommon. The strategy you suggested, of replacing a union by a disjoint union so that its cardinality can be estimated via Jech's definition of infinite sums of cardinals, turns out to be very useful in practice.

Comment: Dear Andrés E. Caicedo,

Thank you for this elaboration. This answers my question.

Comment: Glad to help. Cardinal arithmetic is full of pretty and interesting ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The formula $\cup_{a<l}(a^l)$ is not a presentation of a sum of ordinals. It is the union of  a set of cardinal ordinals. (And therefore  it  $is$ a cardinal ordinal.)

The statement $k^l=\cup_{a<k}(a^l)$ (when  $k$ is an infinite regular cardinal ordinal) and $l$ is an infinite cardinal ordinal)) means (i) $\forall a<k\;(a^l\leq k^l)$ and  (ii) $\forall x\in k^l\;\exists a<k \;(x\in a^k).$

In cardinal arithmetic, when $a$ and $b$ are cardinals then $a^b$ is the cardinal of the set of functions from $b$ to $a$ . So (i) above is obvious.

Comment: Usually  i would go into detail on this but right now I'm sleepy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.